Printing speed vs travel speed
I'm going to buy a new (and faster) 3D printer. I'm a bit confused about the claims of printing speed vs the travel speed (G0, I guess).
For example, let's see the Sovol T300. The specifications says:


Printing speed: ≤ 600 mm/s

and FLASHFORGE 5M Pro:


Maximum speed 600 mm/s

but below in the same page:


Max travel speed: 600 mm/s

So, what does "printing speed" does really mean?
Is really possible to print at 600 mm/s (like Sovol claims) or it's a marketing slogan, but they mean travel speed?
Of course I can write to the manufacturer, but there are tons of 3D printers out there and I'd like to select few before going deeper in the details.

I believe it was mentioned in a Teaching Tech video recently  https://www.youtube.com/@TeachingTech/videos    but can't immediately spot which one.   From memory, the "max 600 mm/s" is possible but the printer accelerates up to that speed, and may not make it without sufficient room in a straight line.  The print bed isn't big enough for that speed to be reached much, before it has to decelerate again.   Answer because memory and no evidence

@Criggie, it makes sense. But my main concern is whether this speed is achieved while estruding or just moving (travelling) in G0 from one position to another without extruding the filament

best I can suggest is watch the Sovol videos in that link.  Could be educational.

i doubt it would be able to extrude fast enough to "print" at 300mms, or even 200mms. For many (most?) shapes, re-visiting too soon on the next layer will be problematic anyway. The travel speed is instructive, and usually faster is better, so long as the cage is stable enough to prevent shaking and warping.
